# How to get the PHP Code Coverage working with phpdbg on a Windows Server?

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, phpdbg, php-code-coverage

Since I still have [troubles with PHPUnit / PHP Code Coverage and Xdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386345/phpunit-or-its-code-coverage-driver-cannot-find-some-interfaces), I decided to try it another way -- with [phpdbg](http://phpdbg.com/).

I did it as [hier](https://thephp.cc/news/2015/08/phpunit-4-8-code-coverage-support) shown. Tried in CMD and also in Git Bash, but the result is the same, it fails:

```
$ composer info | grep "phpunit"
phpunit/php-code-coverage           4.0.0  Library that provides collectio...
phpunit/php-file-iterator           1.4.1  FilterIterator implementation t...
phpunit/php-text-template           1.2.1  Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                   1.0.8  Utility class for timing
phpunit/php-token-stream            1.4.8  Wrapper around PHP's tokenizer ...
phpunit/phpunit                     5.4.6  The PHP Unit Testing framework.
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects        3.2.3  Mock Object library for PHPUnit

$ phpdbg -qrr ./vendor/bin/phpunit -v

dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../phpunit/phpunit" && pwd)

# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        # Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
        # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
        # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
        # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
        if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
                dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
        fi
fi

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/phpunit" "$@"
```

**How to get the combination PHPUnit & PHP Code Coverage & phpdbg working on a Windows Server?**

Comment: Perhaps try directly invoking the phpunit file itself instead of the file in vendor/bin. I.e. `phpdbg -qrr vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` … does that work=

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you! Please make an answer from your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under Windows it seems that files in `vendor/bin` are actually batch files, invoking the original file (and not php files which phpdbg will understand).

In this case:

```
dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../phpunit/phpunit" && pwd)
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
"${dir}/phpunit" "$@"
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

i.e. `../phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` (this path is relative to `vendor/bin`); thus the actual file is at `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`.

And you can invoke it directly via `phpdbg -qrr vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` then.