# phpdbg with php7 always returns [nothing to execute!]

Tags: php, phpdbg

I'm just trying to start up with phpdbg, i have installed it using

```
apt-get install --yes php-phpdbg
```

I'm trying to run phpdbg using:

```
$ phpdbg -qrr vendor/bin/phpunit
```

and

```
$ phpdbg -qrr vendor/bin/phpunit ExampleTest.php
```

ExampleTest.php being

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testBasicTest()
     {
         $response = $this->get('/');
         $response->assertStatus(200);
     }
 }
```

also

```
$ phpdbg -qrr vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml
```

Adding this lines to phpunit.xml

```
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="tests/_reports/logs/clover.xml"/>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="tests/_reports/coverage" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70" />
    <log type="testdox-text" target="tests/_reports/testdox/executed.txt"/>
</logging>
```

But the output is always

> [nothing to execute!]

Comment: Do you need to specify the config? `--configuration phpunit.xml` Been meaning to play with this more but still using xdebug. What specific PHP version you working with?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still the same result.
Updating my question to include this

Comment: Can you do a simpler sanity test on some `hello.php` script perhaps? Nothing in the logs? Thinking it seg faults? Seeing some stuff about stability on certain 7.x versions.  FWIW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398808/how-to-get-the-php-code-coverage-working-with-phpdbg-on-a-windows-server

Comment: @ficuscr, tried it, still the same result, adding that to the question

Comment: And also tried it on windows with the same project, same result